# Ionic 4 Tabs label size?

Tags: ionic-framework, shadow-dom, ionic4, ionic-tabs

How can we change the tab buttons label size in ionic 4? The style is locked inside shadow-DOM:

`:host(.layout-icon-top) .tab-btn{
  --text-font-size: 20px;
  font-size: 20px
}`

I tried like this but it didn't work.